# How do I prevent the Java XML Transformer using "HTML" method from adding <META> tag?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, transform

I'm using the built-in Java XML Transformer to serialize an XML document into text. I'm having a problem however when I am outputting in HTML mode.

Whenever I insert a `head` element the built-in transformer decides to insert a `META` tag with content-type data. I don't want this tag inside my data and I can't seem to find an output parameter that will disable this feature. I know I could build an xslt stylesheet and strip the tag in question, but it would be simpler just to be able to set a parameter on the transformer itself that disables it.

You might respond with "but you really should have this tag" -- trust me, I don't need it, for brevities sake I won't go into it.

Sample code

```
Document d; 
//d = <html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>

Transformer t; //properly inited with no xslt specified

t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD,"html");
t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT,"no");
t.transform(new DOMSource(d), result);

System.out.println(result);
```

returns

```
<html><head><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title></title><style type="text/css"></style></head><body></body></html>
```

Case in point, I don't want that `META` tag there. How do I get rid of it in the easiest way possible?

*UPDATE:*

I've run across the option `{http://xml.apache.org/xalan}omit-meta-tag` which is supposed to do what I'm looking for. However it seems as though it's being ignored.

Comment: set **xml** value of OutputKeys.METHOD.

Comment: it needs to be html for what i'm doing

Comment: That's standard behavior according to XSLT' [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-HTML-Output-Method) and it's required by browsers if you use other character set encode than default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a complicated situation, as it seems the `"{http://xml.apache.org/xalan}omit-meta-tag"` is ignored in the built-in java transform.

So the short answer is to download something like xalanj and put it in your classpath manually.

Comment: If you do that, you'll have to ensure that you put it in the endorsed directory, so that it overrides the version built in to Java.  See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/standards/ for details.

Answer (score 6):

Try added below:

```
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
trans.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
```