# Validation error for HTML5 document using windows-1252 encoding

Tags: html, utf-8, windows-1252

The w3.org HTML validator https://validator.w3.org unexpectedly shows an error for a HTML5 document which uses the encoding iso-8859-1.

The message is:

> `Error` Legacy encoding windows-1252 used. Documents must use UTF-8.

I found many resources which only indicate UTF-8 being the recommended encoding.
Did I miss something, or is the w3 validator error message questionable?

---

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
    <title>Untitled document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
       à la mode 
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That character encoding only covers latin characters. Nowadays, one should be using utf8. I have not seen windows-1252 on any modern web site in many, many years.

Comment: Regarding the meta http-equiv ..., unfortunately the standard (built-in) DOM to HTML transformer in Java (versions 8 to 17) always emits this meta tag,. Xalan, which can be used instead of the standard transformer, allows to set a proprietary flag - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409300/80901 - to omit the meta tag. My example is based on a conversion using the built-in transformer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In HTML5, to specify the document's charset, you should use the newer `<meta charset="...">` instead of the older `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=...">` (which is still supported for legacy reasons), eg:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="windows-1252">
    <title>Untitled document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
       à la mode 
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

But, that being said, the current HTML5 standard states:

> 4.2.5.4 Specifying the document's character encoding
>
> A character encoding declaration is a mechanism by which the character encoding used to store or transmit a document is specified.
>
> **The Encoding standard requires use of the UTF-8 character encoding and requires use of the "utf-8" encoding label to identify it.** Those requirements necessitate that the document's character encoding declaration, if it exists, specifies an encoding label using an ASCII case-insensitive match for "utf-8". Regardless of whether a character encoding declaration is present or not, **the actual character encoding used to encode the document must be UTF-8**.

As well as:

> Encoding declaration state (http-equiv="content-type")
>
> The Encoding declaration state is just an alternative form of setting the charset attribute: it is a character encoding declaration. This state's user agent requirements are all handled by the parsing section of the specification.
>
> For meta elements with an http-equiv attribute in the Encoding declaration state, the content attribute must have a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for a string that consists of: the literal string "text/html;", optionally followed by any number of ASCII whitespace, **followed by the literal string "charset=utf-8"**.

Which means, the validator is correct. You are not allowed to use `Windows-1252`/`ISO-8859-1` (or any other charset) anymore in modern HTML, only UTF-8.  It is not just a recommendation, it is a requirement.

Whether or not particular web browsers choose to *enforce* this requirement is another matter, though...

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! Regarding the meta http-equiv ..., unfortunately the standard (built-in) DOM to HTML transformer in Java (versions 8 to 17) always emits this meta tag,. Xalan, which can be used instead of the standard transformer, allows to set a proprietary flag - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1409300/80901 - to omit the meta tag. My example is based on a conversion using the built-in transformer.

Comment: Then I would consider the transformer to be flawed, since `<meta charset="...">` has been the official way to declare the document's charset in HTML5 since day 1. If the transformer is emitting `<!DOCTYPE html>` to declare HTML5, then it should have also been emitting `<meta charset="...">`.